# how to edit a table value which is an integer

Tags: javascript, html

How can I access a table's value with a button click and add the value `5` to it after every click?
My current solution just adds the `5` as a string, but I want that `20` will be `25` and not `205`, here's my current approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table id="table" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Emma</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="ageUpdate();" value="Add 5 to the age">

<script>
function ageUpdate() 
{
    var David_Age=document.getElementById('table').rows[parseInt(1,10)].cells;
    David_Age[parseInt(3,10)].innerHTML += 5;
    
    var Emma_Age=document.getElementById('table').rows[parseInt(2,10)].cells;
    Emma_Age[parseInt(3,10)].innerHTML += 5;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solved it:**    `David_Age[parseInt(3,10)].innerHTML = parseInt(David_Age[parseInt(3,10)].innerHTML) + 5`

Comment: Just a tip `parseInt(3,10)` for an index is not needed, the indexes are always in the decimal number system. So `David_Age[3]` is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get the value, sum it, and then attribute it to cell.

Something like that:

`David_Age[3].innerHTML = parseInt(David_Age[3].innerHTML) + 5;`